# Remove invalid string entries (\n) from numeric column variables

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a set of columns A1-A54. All these columns are supposed to be formatted as numeric. However, some entries in these columns are stored as "\N" which are corrupting the column formats and not allowing to run operations like proc means on the columns. Wanted to understand how can I set these values to missing by running a loop across all columns.

I tried running an do loop using array *numeric* over all the columns but due to \N being present in some columns, they are getting formatted as string variables and the array approach is not working.

```
array nums[*] _numeric_;
if nums[i]='\N' then nums[i]=.;
end;
```

This is not converting the \N to missing values as SAS is interpreting them as strings in numeric variables and throwing an error.

Error-String variable found in Numeric column. While running the loop.

Comment: Show the code you are using to create your data set with columns A1-A54

Comment: Where is the `\N` "stored" if not in a character varaible?  Are you reading the data from a text file? If so then change the way you are reading the variables so that they are defined as numeric instead of character.

Comment: You need to go back and clean up your data import. `\n` is likely either a missing value or a line break that got read in that shouldn't have. The issues is likely a few steps back and I strongly recommend you go back and fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The import process that finds data that is non-numeric will cause that column to be `_character_`, so some of your `A1-A54` are character.

What happens if you code this ?

```
array mydata A1-A54;
```

Do you see

```
ERROR: All variables in array list must be the same type, i.e., all numeric or character.
```

You will need to identify the `A` columns that are character and convert their values to like named numerics (when possible), when the conversion is not possible the numeric value will be missing (as expected).

Example:

```
data have;
  length a1 8 a2-a4 $15; %* pretend the import created a mixed bag of types;
  row = 1;
  a1 = 123;
  a2 = '123' || byte(10) || '456';
  a3 = byte(10);
  a4 = '123';
  output;
  row = 2;
  a1 = 456;
  a2 = '789' || byte(10) || 'XYZ';
  a3 = '987';
  a4 = byte(10);
  output;
run;

proc contents noprint data=have out=have_meta;
run;

proc sql noprint;
  select 
    cats(name,'= char',name),
    cats(name,'= input(char', name,',??best12.);'),
    'char'||name
  into 
    :rename separated by ' ',
    :convert separated by ' ',
    :drop separated by ' '
  from have_meta 
  where 
    type=2 and
    (substr(name,1,1) in ('a', 'A'))  /* the characters of the A-team :) */
  ;
quit;

options symbolgen;
data want(drop=&drop);
  set have (rename=(&rename));
  &convert

run;

options nosymbolgen;
```